# setCenter() based on specific marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to ask a question regarding marker in Google Map. How do I target to specific marker if I have multiple marker in the map?

I already add multiple marker in the map code below :

```
var markers = [], marker;

function setMarker()
{
    var infoWindowContent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        infoWindowContent[i] = '<div id="content">' +'<h2>' +locations[i][0] +'</h2>' +'<div id="bodyContent"><p>Latitude: ' +locations[i][1] +'<br/>Longitude: ' +locations[i][2] +'<br/>Speed: ' +locations[i][3] +'KM/h</div></div>';

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            id: locations[i][4],
            icon: 'http://pickndrop.my/img/school_bus.png'
            });

            markers.push(marker);

            // Display multiple markers on a map
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                map.setCenter(marker.position);
                }
            })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

In code above I already make an array to push all the markers. Now I want to target a specific marker, so that I can change the map center based on user input (from drop list). For example, when user pick a Marker 1 the map center will change to marker 1. I try using the code below, but it is not working.

```
<select id="children" onchange="setTarget()">
    <option value="0">Marker 1</option>
    <option value="1">Marker 2</option>
</select>


function setTarget()
{   
    var x = document.getElementById('children').value;
    map.setCenter(markers[x].getPosition());
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since this was actually working I suggest that you just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The codes above are working fine, it is my false not to retrieve value from database correctly.